# Format a hyperlink to open the C drive

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am showing a list of hyperlinks on a web page that are intended to open windows explorer at the folder containing the file. The file paths are stored in a database and retrieved.

If the file path in question is showing in my C# code as `\\\\myserver\\folder1\\somedocument.doc`

I can set the href of the hyperlink to be: `file://\\\\myserver\\folder1` and it works. Windows Explorer opens and shows the contents of folder1.

But, if the user who originally specified the file, selected one on his C:\ drive, I might have a path like this to deal with `C:\\Somefile.txt`

In this case I want to format the hyperlink so that it opens Windows Explorer and shows the contents of the C: drive. How can I do this?

Comment: You should be aware that opening windows explorer this way will only work with IE. Security protocols implemented by other browsers don't allow this. I'd recommend not using this for the sake of consistency.

Comment: It's IE only on an intranet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`file:///C:/` would work. But note, that this is **only** working in Internet Explorer. Neither Chrome, nor Firefox support such a behaviour. (Chrome and Firefox will list the drive's content in the browser instead of opening Windows-Explorer)

There are extensions for chrome, but i dont think, that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is IE. As I say, it's not working for me.

I'm beginning to wonder if this is anything to do with the fact that my development box is a virtual machine that I connect to with VMware Client.

Answer (score 0):

`file:///c:/` should work for this

Comment: I hard coded the NavigateUrl of my hyperlink to file://c:/ but nothing happens when I click on it. If I look at the properties of the hyperlink it says:
Protocol: File Protocol

Type: File

Address: file:///c:/

It doesn't open Windows Explorer though

Comment: If I put this in an html page: <a href="file:///c:/">Open c</a> and then click it in IE it does indeed open explorer viewing the c drive. Which version of IE are you using perhaps old ones do something different. There is no way of explicitly specifiying to open explorer, it will depend on how the client is setup to handle file:// protocol

Comment: Well, just done exactly as you did - and clicking on it does nothing. I'm going to have to ask the network boys. My development box is a virtual machine that I connect to with VMware Client - maybe the c drive is a figment of my imagination!

Comment: It'll be security, I was running the HTML page locally, if you're running off a server, or remote machine, it will probably be blocked. It may work if you add the site to your trusted sites? Have you seen this: http://dyslexicanaboko.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/work-around-to-opening-up-local-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

It should work just the same as a network path. Have you tried `file://c:\`?
Other users will not be able to see that file of course, only the one that submitted it.

Comment: I have tried hard coding the url to point to file://c:\\ but it does not seem to work. Clicking on the hyperlink does nothing.

If I look at the properties of the hyperlink it shows Address as ... file:///c:/

Comment: I tested here with a local HTML page. Internet Explorer 9 opens Windows Explorer. Chrome, Firefox and Opera show a file listing in the browser window.

Comment: And all of those browsers block the link from opening when its not a local webpage. For security reasons probably. The reason it works for a network share is probably because those are in the same security zone.

Answer (score -1):

To open C:\ by default you can use: "explorer.exe /e,C:\"
Same syntax applies to fileshare: "explorer.exe /e,\myserver\folder1"

Comment: And how do you want to run a CMD-Command on a clients machine? Security 2.0 ?